# C# PictureBox - Can't make it work

Tags: c#, winforms, image, picturebox

I'm having trouble displaying a PictureBox in C#. I have two forms. In my main form I'm calling the other form, where the PictureBox is located.

This is how I am calling the second form:

```
        frmODeck oDeck = new frmODeck();
        oDeck.Show();
```

Now, this is my second form, where the PictureBox is located from main form

```
namespace Shuffle_Cards
{
public partial class frmODeck : Form
{
    private PictureBox picBox;
    private Image image;


    public frmODeck()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void frmODeck_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        image = Image.FromFile("C:\\C2.jpg");
        picBox = new PictureBox();

        picBox.Location = new Point(75, 20);
        picBox.Image = image;

        picBox.Show();
    }

    public void getCards()
    {

    }
}
}
```

What am I doing wrong, or what am I missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The picture-box control needs to be added to the control-collection of the top-level control it should belong to - in the case, the form itself. Relevant: [`Control.Controls`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controls%28VS.71%29.aspx).

Replace:

```
picBox.Show();
```

with:

```
Controls.Add(picBox);
```

Answer (score -1):

Befor you do a picBox.Show(); , you need to add it to the Controls of the window you are loading, with the code @Ani provided:

```
Controls.Add(picBox);
```

That should do it!